# Using the cin.getLine()

Tags: c++

I am having a problem using the cin.getLine()

```
/*
 * 
 */

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  char *first, last;


  cout << "Enter your first anames: ";
  cin.getline(first,255);
  cout << "Your initials are " << first;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: And what is the problem? (What do you want to accomplish, and what does actually happen?)

Answer (score 2):

`cin.getline(first, 255)` extracts characters from `cin` and stores them as a c-string into the array beginning at `first` which means that `first` has to be initialized first. Check [this example](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/getline/).

You can declare `first` as a static array: `char first[256];` or you can declare it as `std::string` and use `getline(cin, first)` instead.

Answer (score 2):

first is not initialized. It is not pointing to a character array.

Since you are using C++:

```
std::string first; 
getline(cin, first);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are defining a char pointer `first` and a char `last`. You should be defining two buffers: `char first[1024], last[1024]`. This allows you to allocate memory space for your arrays.